# iOS UITableViewCell different behavior after commitEditingStyle

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi in my app I've a tableview in which there are a list of customer. I added the `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to delete one row of my list of customer. When the iPad is running iOS 9 when I do the gesture I saw a white area at the right edge of the `UITableViewCell`, but when I run it on iOS 10 this white area doesn't appear.

[image]

Why is that? It's not a big problem, but I think it's better if i fix it. Thank you.